# Compare courses values with PyMongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to print all the passed courses from this JSON registry:

```
"name": "Morton Fitzgerald" ,"email": "mortonfitzgerald@ontagene.com","courses":[{"course 1": 10, "course 2": 3,"course 3": 8}
```

I need to print out every `course 'x' >= 5` with a the script below:

```
student = students.find_one({"$and":[{"email":data['email']},{"courses":{'$exists': True}}]})
   if (student!=None):
       course = students.find({},{"courses":1})
       course_list = []
       for student in course:
         if ({"courses":{"$gte": 5}}):
            course_list.append(student)
            student = {"name":data['name'], course_list}
            return Response(json.dumps(student), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
         else:
            return Response("There are no courses available for this student", status=400, mimetype='application/json')
  else: 
     return Response("Not authenticated user", status=401, mimetype='application/json')
```

**Error that I get:**

```
KeyError: 'name'
```

**Desired output:**

```
Morton Fitzgerald, "course 1": 10, "course 3": 8
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You try to check if statement

```
if len(data) != 0:
```

or

```
if not data.empty:
```

Comment: Yes but the script seems that doesn't compare the values of courses in for loop.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to explain but I don't understand which if statement to replace. I guess you mean student!=None ?